# Continue Spring Kafka Startup even on Kafka Connection Failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

Is there a configuration I can use to instruct Spring to continue on startup and initialize the `Beans` even if Kafka connection failed?

I am using Spring Framework 5.2.3 and Spring Kafka 2.5.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need kafka beans for your application to work in every use case then continue with startup if there is no kafka connection makes no sense. Your application will not be able to do anything without kafka.

But if some parts of your application do not need kafka and you would like to use only those parts then you can either mark kafka related beans as lazy or make all beans lazy by default. In this case spring will create beans only when they are actually needed. And even if there is no kafka connection available parts of your app that do not need kafka will work.